# Rails selector which has options a set of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I want to make a form in which the user can select a number between 1 and 30. I am trying to do something like this:

```
<%= f.select("@currency.neural_network", "prediction_days", [1..30]) %>
```

However, I am getting the below error.

```
Failure/Error: click_link 'Show'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `merge' for [1..30]:Array
```

The code for the entire form is:

```
<%= form_for @currency.neural_network do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Days" %><br />
    <%= f.select("@currency.neural_network", "prediction_days", [1..30]) %>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to remove "@currency.neural_network" since you're using the form_for helper. It already knows that's the object you're referencing. select_tag is different from form_helper.select (in that it's missing the 'object' argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select). Assuming you want `prediction_days` to be passed to your controller as a value between 1 and 30, and `prediction_days` is an attribute of a `neural_network` object, then the following should work for you:

```
<%= f.select(:prediction_days, options_for_select(1..30)) %>
```

Comment: I have changed that line of code as you suggested, but I can select only one option( the number 1).

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
<%= f.number_field(:days, in: 1..30, step: 1) %>
# => <input id="currency_days" max="30" min="1" name="currency[days]" step="1" type="number">
```

It basically returns you an html input tag of type "number" from 1 to 30 incremented 1 by 1. Is it what you are lookin for ?

Comment: Some explanation would be great

Comment: Updated my answer to be more accurate